# How to send multiple table data in a single view without joining the table in laravel 9?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-9

I'm new to laravel and I'm trying to build a landing page. In my database, I've multiple tables like:

- hero_section
- portfolio
- about
- skill..

So, there will be multiple sections on my landing page, and in order to do that, I need to send these tables data separately without joining them and pass it into a single view.

This is my **route web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'show']);
```

My controller **HomeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\HeroSectionModel;
use App\Models\AboutModel;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){

        // $hero_section = HeroSectionModel::select("*")->where('ID', '=', 1)->get();
        $hero_section = HeroSectionModel::all();
        $about = AboutModel::all();

        // return view('home',compact('hero_section'));
        return View('home')
        ->with('hero_section',$hero_section)
        ->with('about',$about);
    }
}
```

And in my **home.blade.php** I'm trying to access data like this:

```
<section>
  <div class="row">
    <p>{{ $hero_section->NAME }}</p>
    <p>{{ $hero_section->CAREER_OBJECTIVE }}</p>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="row">
    <p>{{ $about->DESCRIPTION }}</p>
    <p>{{ $hero_section->DESCRIPTION1 }}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

In this way, I'm unable to fetch any data. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in controller:

```
 $res["hero_section"]=$hero_section;
 $res["about"]=$about;
 return view('home',$res);
```

in blade file:

```
 @foreach ($hero_section as $hero)
  <div class="row">
      <p>{{ $hero->NAME }}</p>
      <p>{{ $hero->CAREER_OBJECTIVE }}</p>
 </div>
 @endforeach
 @foreach ($about as $a)
  <div class="row">
      <p>{{ $a->DESCRIPTION}}</p>
      <p>{{ $a->DESCRIPTION1}}</p>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller try this,

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\HeroSectionModel;
use App\Models\AboutModel;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function show()
    {
        $hero_sections = HeroSectionModel::all();
        $abouts = AboutModel::all();

        return view('home', [
            'hero_sections' => $hero_sections,
            'abouts' => $abouts 
        ]);
    }
}
```

Inside your blade file

```
<section>
  @foreach($hero_sections as $hero_section)
  <div class="row">
    <p>{{ $hero_section->name }}</p>
    <p>{{ $hero_section->career_objective }}</p>
  </div>
  @endforeach
</section>

<section>
  @foreach($abouts as $about)
  <div class="row">
    <p>{{ $about->description }}</p>
    <p>{{ $about->description1 }}</p>
  </div>
</section>
```